# How to store selected value of unordered list or ordered list into variable?

Tags: javascript

Let say I have an unordered list:

```
<ul id="list">
<li>Option1</li>
<li>Option2</li>
<li>Option3</li>
<li>Option4</li>
<li>Option5</li>
<li>Option6</li>
</ul>
```

So, whenever any of the list item selected or just gets clicked on by the user, it should store the selected value in x variable.

Looking for answer with plain JavaScript.

Thank you

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- catch all elements with `getElementsByTagName` function
- use `forEach` function to bind a `click` event on every `li` element.
- if user clicks on specified `li` element, log it's `innerHTML` value

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var selected;

Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('click', function(){
  selected = this.innerHTML;
  console.log(selected);
}));
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>Option1</li>
  <li>Option2</li>
  <li>Option3</li>
  <li>Option4</li>
  <li>Option5</li>
  <li>Option6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this is actually shows in the console log but how can I store what has been selected into variable so i can display that in different part of the page ? @king user

Comment: @AbdullahOmran Just make a variable and store it inside :) Check edit.

Comment: Can you please explain why when I called the variable outside the function won't show what has been stored in it? the code works perfectly. @king user

Comment: @AbdullahOmran If you put `var selected` into the `forEach()` function's body, it will still work because whole logic is stored inside. Show me what exactly do you mean.

Comment: Here is exactly what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/abdullah7omran/dn902wks/1/

Comment: @AbdullahOmran It works, but it **will not** show any results, because you just calling it **once**, when the page reloads. And there's no result because your `arr1` is empty :) You have to call with every function call, to **update** the result :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x; 
document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click",function(a) {
        if(a.target && a.target.nodeName == "LI") {
            x = a.target.innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
        }
    });
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>Option1</li>
  <li>Option2</li>
  <li>Option3</li>
  <li>Option4</li>
  <li>Option5</li>
  <li>Option6</li>
</ul>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: this sounds more like what I am looking for but when I tried to show whatever the user has selected from the list, nothing was shown. I added Paragraph tag ID in script  and .innerHTML= x; @Gokkul

Comment: Can you please explain why when I wrote the same line but outside the function won't work ? the code works perfectly :) @Gokkul

Comment: The code does not work that way because the function is attached to the click event. Before the click event is registered, the entire code gets executed by the JS Engine. Hence the array element will be set to undefined initially.  The array will get populated with values only after the click event is registered. That is why when the array is called outside the function, it will not work as it has no value.